# Order get_terms by multiple meta_values

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, order, terms

I'm trying to get all the terms of a custom taxonomy (`ediciones`) but ordered by two ACF fields: `edicion_ano` (year field) and `edicion_numero` (number field). First should order by year and next by the number field.

I understand from ACF (5.5.X) it's possible to use `meta_query` and I'm ussing version 5.5.14.

> In the new version of ACF (5.5.x) now uses term meta and WP allows
>   meta queries for terms, so these work-arounds should no longer be
>   needed. ([source](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/sort-taxonomy-terms/))

Right now I'm using this code:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'ediciones',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'edicion_ano_param' => array(
            'key' => 'edicion_ano',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'edicion_numero_param' => array(
            'key' => 'edicion_numero',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'edicion_ano_param' => 'DESC',
        'edicion_numero_param' => 'DESC',
    ),
);

$ediciones = get_terms($args);
```

Using the same `meta_query` but with `get_posts()` it's working fine.
Actually with `get_terms()` show me a warning but I don't know why: **Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in .../class-wp-term-query.php on line 824**

If I try order just for **one field** works fine with this code:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'ediciones',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'meta_key' => 'edicion_ano',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$ediciones = get_terms($args);
```

But I need order by both fields. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how can make this works how I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is because `get_terms()` does not accept array type as a value for the 'orderby' parameter. The documentation says about this parameter:

> **'orderby'**
>
> (string) Field(s) to order terms by. Accepts term fields
>   ('name', 'slug', 'term_group', 'term_id', 'id', 'description'),
>   'count' for term taxonomy count, 'include' to match the 'order' of the
>   $include param, 'meta_value', 'meta_value_num', the value of
>   $meta_key, the array keys of $meta_query, or 'none' to omit the ORDER
>   BY clause. Defaults to 'name'.

You can see here the original documentation [page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#parameters)

Comment: That's true @Picard, my mistake. So, if `orderby` doesn't accept array type and is only string, how could I order by two fields the `get_terms()`? I can't figure out how to do it, can you help me? Thanks!